# Can an NFT own other NFTs?

Tags: erc-721, nft

Ok so this is a bit abstract, but imagine you have two ERC-721 contracts: `GameCharacter` and `Weapon`. You want each `GameCharacter` to own a `Weapon`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a draft proposal [EIP 998 - Composable Non-Fungible Token Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-998). That allows creating a hierarchy of tokens.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't supported by the standard.

But you can extend the standard functionality with whatever functionality you want. And even with the standard functionality, you can encode this kind of ownership data in the NFT metadata, in some way. But this will require some special handling of the metadata.

So it's doable, but third parties won't understand it, since it's not standard functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Lauri is correct, this is not directly supported by the standard.

But understanding that product development trumps standards. Always focus on the product! I have created a demonstration of this approach.

Code is published at -> http://nft.life. Thank you to Chain 76 and NFT.nyc for sponsoring this project.

Additionally it allows to create tokens in batch and transfer them as batch. Batch can be large numbers. We demonstrated live on stage minting and transferring 2^128 tokens on mainnet.

Comment: It's not all unicorns and rainbows, there were compromises made to allow those exact things to be possible mentioned above, and only you fully understanding your application can decide if those tradeoffs are worth it